# Redirect URL Path

Tags: 7, uri, redirection

I need to add a redirect that makes all traffic going to the first URL path below to the second URL path. This needs to be done in a bulk fashion for all pages listed under this path.

```
www.site.com/PATH/page
to
www.site.com/page
```

I've installed the module [Match Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect) and began experimenting but I can't get it to work the way I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Match Redirect" module will redirect all matching patterns to only *one* target path. Here's relevant paragraph from the project page:

> Only the source patterns can have wildcards. The target url is a single page and I have no plans to add wildcards to the target url.

To answer your question, you can do this is via `.htaccess`. Here's an example:

```
RewriteRule ^OLD-PATH/(.*)$ /NEW-PATH/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I think it will work if you add these rules at the top of the `.htaccess` file, so they are executed before Drupal's rules.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

One other way, without using additional modules would be to create a content with the alias **oldurl** adding the following full html content to the body:

```
<script>
window.location="http://www.yoursite.com/newurl"
</script>
```